# Is it possible to index numpy array with sympy symbols?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Helle I want to do some summation on a numpy array like this

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
import cv2

i, j = sy.symbols('i j', Integer=True)
#next read some grayscale image to create a numpy array of pixels  
a = cv2.imread(filename)
b = sy.summation(sy.summation(a[i][j], (i,0,1)), (j,0,1)) #double summation
```

but I'm facing with an error. is it possible to handle numpy symbols as numpy arrays'indexes? if not can you sugest me a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to use symbolic summation? Is there any property you want to use for those symbols? It looks to me that normal summation is what you need: `sum(sum(a))`. The inner `sum` sums over columns, second over rows. If you are interested in the reverse, you can use `sum(sum(a.transpose())` instead.

Comment: juandesat say I have an array of pixels with shape (row,col) expressed by a numpy array next I divide it into 3*3 blocks of pixels centered in each P(i,j) where P(i,j) is the pixels at (i,j) in the whole numpy array. what I want is to calculate the average pixels value for each 3*3 blocks image as the new value of P(i,j) so "i" and "j" will be dynamics. The array is just an exemple but what I what is to use sympy symbols as an indice for numpy array. Thanks

Comment: I can even ask my question in another direction: is it possible to get the value of a sympy symbol as a python integer value for example?

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe SymPy functions usually operate on SymPy objects, e.g. `Symbol` instances. Usually you formulate an equation symbolically, and then generate a callback using e.g. `lambdify` which then may operate on numpy arrays.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use numpy object directly in SymPy expressions, because numpy objects don't know how to deal with symbolic variables.

Instead, create the thing you want symbolically using SymPy objects, and then `lambdify` it. The SymPy version of a numpy array is IndexedBase, but it seems there is a bug with it, so, since your array is 2-dimensional, you can also use MatrixSymbol.

```
In [49]: a = MatrixSymbol('a', 2, 2) # Replace 2, 2 with the size of the array

In [53]: i, j = symbols('i j', integer=True)

In [50]: f = lambdify(a, Sum(a[i, j], (i, 0, 1), (j, 0, 1)))

In [51]: b = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [52]: f(b)
Out[52]: 10
```

(also note that the correct syntax for creating integer symbols is `symbols('i j', integer=True)`, not `symbols('i j', Integer=True)`).

Note that you have to use `a[i, j]` instead of `a[i][j]`, which isn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

MatrixSymbol is limited to 2-dimensional matrices.  To generalize to arrays of
any dimension, you can generate the expression with `IndexedBase`. `lambdify` is
currently incompatible with `IndexedBase`, but it can be used with
`DeferredVectors`. So the trick is pass a `DeferredVector` to `lambdify`:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np

a = sy.IndexedBase('a')
i, j, k = sy.symbols('i j k', integer=True)
s = sy.Sum(a[i, j, k], (i, 0, 1), (j, 0, 1), (k, 0, 1))
f = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('a'), s)
b = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)

result = f(b)
expected = b[:2,:2,:2].sum()
assert expected == result
```