# How do I use a python array in a symbolic expression?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, sympy

For a project I want to use `sympy` to construct and compute the maximum likelihood of a gaussian distribution for a discrete number of data points.
The method I follow can be found at [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumLikelihood.html%22maximum%20likelihood%22).

But I ran into trouble when I attempted to use an array in a symbolic expression with `Product` and/or `Sum`. Below is a simplified version of my earlier attempts.

In notebook in Anaconda's Yupyter, I create a python array, say `x`:

```
N = 10
x = range(N)
```

And I want to use `x` in a symbolic expression in `sympy` as follows:

```
from sympy import *, Symbol
i = Symbol('i', integer=True)
mu = Symbol('mu')

s = Sum( (x[i]-mu)**2, (i, 0, N-1))
```

But this doesn't work, because evaluating the cell results in:

```
TypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-19c174235872> in <module>()
      7 mu = Symbol('mu')
      8 
----> 9 s = Sum( (x[i]-mu)**2, (i,0,N-1))

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Symbol
```

Another attempt:

```
X = MatrixSymbol(X, 1, N)  # No clue how to convince `sympy` to use 1-dimensional arrays using only one index.

s = Sum((X[0,i]-mu)**2, (i,0,N-1))
s.doit()
```

Gives:

```
(-mu + X[0, 0])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 1])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 2])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 3])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 4])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 5])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 6])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 7])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 8])**2 + (-mu + X[0, 9])**2
```

kind of works, but how to get the *real* values for `x` into that symbolic expression, i.e. substituting each of these `X[0,i]` for the value of `x[i]`?

Another attempt:

```
X = Matrix(1,N, range(N))

s = Sum((X[i]-mu)**2, (i, 0, N-1))
s.doit()
```

Now is python/sympy very unhappy:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6d106fb975e1> in <module>()
      1 X = Matrix(1,N, range(N))
      2 
----> 3 s = Sum((X[i]-mu)**2, (i, 0, N-1))
      4 s.doit()

/Users/twan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
     94             if isinstance(key, slice):
     95                 return self._mat[key]
---> 96             return self._mat[a2idx(key)]
     97 
     98     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

/Users/twan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.pyc in a2idx(j, n)
   4412             j = j.__index__()
   4413         except AttributeError:
-> 4414             raise IndexError("Invalid index a[%r]" % (j, ))
   4415     if n is not None:
   4416         if j < 0:

IndexError: Invalid index a[i]
```

I've no clue what to try else and I'm stuck with `sympy` here.   I'm curious whether I ran into a limitation of `sympy` for an very important computation in statistics.

**EDIT**:

I should have mentioned that the summand was to be developed into `(E**(-((x-mu)**2)/(2 * s**2)))/(s * sqrt(2 * pi))`. The exponentiation makes it a slightly different problem.

Although @unutbu's solution didn't work for me, trying to use that suggestion pointed out to me that I should restrain the domains to the real numbers.

@Marshmallow's suggestion did work, the complete solution is now:

```
from sympy import symbols, E, pi, sqrt, init_printing
from sympy import diff, IndexedBase
from sympy.solvers import solve

x, mu = symbols('x mu', real=True)
sigma = symbols('sigma', real=True, positive=True)

bell = (E**(-((x-mu)**2)/(2 * sigma**2)))/(sigma * sqrt(2 * pi))

def likelihood(factor, xs):
    return np.prod([factor.subs(x,i) for i in xs])

def loglikelihood(factor, xs):
    return expand_log(log(likelihood(factor, xs)))

N = 3
X = IndexedBase('X')
Xs = [X[i] for i in range(N)]

solve(diff(loglikelihood(gauss,Xs), mu).subs(sigma, 1), mu)
```

Many thanks to @Marshmellow and @unutbu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your list `x` is numeric, you don't need a symbolic sum to handle it. Just sum the list of `(xi-mu)**2` using Python's list comprehension:

```
from sympy import *
N = 10
x = range(N)
mu = Symbol('mu')
s = sum([(xi-mu)**2 for xi in x])
print(s)
print(s.diff(mu))     # to show this is a symbolic expression
```

Output:

```
mu**2 + (-mu + 1)**2 + (-mu + 2)**2 + (-mu + 3)**2 + (-mu + 4)**2 + (-mu + 5)**2 + (-mu + 6)**2 + (-mu + 7)**2 + (-mu + 8)**2 + (-mu + 9)**2
20*mu - 90
```

Comment: Thanks @Marshmallow,  your suggestion to use a sum or product over a list comprehension put me on the right track.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `IndexedBase` to represent an array that contains elements.

```
X = sy.IndexedBase('X')
s = sy.Sum((X[i]-mu)**2, (i, 0, N-1))
```

It is possible to use `lambdify` to replace SymPy symbols with NumPy arrays. In this case, we want to replace `X[i]` with values from a NumPy array.

Currently, `lambdify` [can not be applied to `IndexedBase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315408/190597) objects. But it can be applied to `DeferredVector`s. For example:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np

i = sy.Symbol('i', integer=True)
mu = sy.Symbol('mu')

N = 10
X = sy.IndexedBase('X')
s = sy.Sum(sy.exp((X[i]-mu)**2), (i, 0, N-1))

f = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('X'), s, 'sympy')
x = np.arange(N)
print(f(x))
```

prints

```
exp(mu**2) + exp((-mu + 1)**2) + exp((-mu + 2)**2) + exp((-mu + 3)**2) + exp((-mu + 4)**2) + exp((-mu + 5)**2) + exp((-mu + 6)**2) + exp((-mu + 7)**2) + exp((-mu + 8)**2) + exp((-mu + 9)**2)
```

Note that since `f(x)` is still a SymPy expression, I used `'sympy'` as the third argument to `lambdify` so that `sy.exp` is not replaced by a numerical `exp` function.

Comment: your solution seems to have trouble when I use `sy.exp(X[i]-mu)**2)` as the summand.  Sympy complains that it can't print a float!  Which is not too surprising as I can imagine that the solution in all its generality is represented in Sympy as an expression of imaginary number.

Comment: I'm not sure how to restrain the domain of the indexed base `X` to the real numbers like you can when declaring normal symbols using `Symbol`.

Comment: Since `mu` is still a symbol, `f(x)` is still symbolic. Therefore you don't want `sy.exp` to be replaced by a numerical `exp` function. Use `f = sy.lambdify(sy.DeferredVector('X'), s, 'sympy')` to prevent `sy.exp` from being replaced by a numerical exp function.